# Ignore "Invalid Column Name" for tables where a column does not exist

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to tell sql server (within a query) that it's OK to ignore a column if it does not exist in a table?

The use case is:
Some tables have an `isDeleted` column, but not all of them.
Throughout the application do not return records where `isDeleted` is `TRUE`.

Ideally, it would be nice to add this at the lowest level possible in our app so all queries include `AND isDeleted=FALSE`, but would not break the query if the `isDeleted` column doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you considered the opposite approach, i.e. adding the `isDeleted` column to all tables where it doesn't already exist?

Comment: Yes, it's certainly an option but not nearly as convenient considering the majority of the tables will never use it. Seems like that might be the winning approach though

Comment: Well it shouldn't be too inconvenient either: adding it is a one-time task and after that you include it in your regular DB design/build/deploy process. Alternatively, if you're using some kind of ORM or DAL then you might be able to handle it at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to tell sql server (within a query) that it's OK to ignore a column if it does not exist in a table?

No, there isn't.

SQL databases have schemas for a reason - as a programmer it is your responsibility to query your database correctly.

You need to be sure to only query for a `isDeleted` column on tables that it is defined on.

Comment: Sure, they have schemas for a reason but they also have functions for a reason. I've seen this type of function included in a couple proprietary query languages, which is why I ask